# Laravel - Get Data of Multiple Tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i would like make a select from two tables, clients and loans. The query (In MySQL syntax) would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM loans, clients WHERE loans.status = 1 AND loans.client_id = clients.id;
```

This are my models:

```
class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function loans()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Loan');
    }
}

class Loan extends Eloquent {
    public function clients()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

How it would be the function using the eloquent model?

Comment: If you have the relationship in loans to attach to the client it belongs to then why now get all the loans with status=1 and just use that object to pull the client info. $loans = Loans::where('status',1)->get(); then $loans->clients()->field

Comment: Okay, i get the part of bring all the loans ($loans = Loans::where('status',1_->get())

Comment: But, how it would be this: $loans->clients()->field?? How it would be the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `with` method to get the loans and clients in one query rather than a separate query for each client.

```
$loans = Loans::with('clients')->where('status', 1)->get();
```

See the docs on [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for more info.

This will get you a collection of Loans which each contains a collection of Clients. If you want to iterate all the loans and clients, you could use a nested loop:

```
foreach ($loans as $loan) {
    // show loan info
    foreach ($loans->clients as $client) {
        // show client info
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want

`Loans::with('clients')->get();`

here is documentation of eager loading
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading